# How to clear(uncheck the filter) the filterred query in elasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

```
GET /Spotafood/Restaurants/_search
{
"query": {
    "match": {
       "name": "Pizza"
    }
}
, "filter": {
    "and": {
       "filters": [
          {
              "term": {
                 "Location": "New Jersey"
              }
          } ,
          {
              "term": {
                 "Cusines": "Pizza"
            }
          }  ,{
              "numeric_range": {
                 "rating": {
                    "from": 1,
                    "to": 5
                 }
              }
          }
       ]
    }
}
}
```

I have created some filters as above. Suppose if i dont want to filter the location, (ie, include results from all locations) is it possible to achieve with any wildcards without rewriting the Query?

Comment: have you tried a wildcard? what happened?

Comment: I tried "*" and " " .But it didn't helped. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use a match all filter ("filter" : {
            "match_all" : { }
        }), but I am guessing you want to keep the structure the same and leave in the "term" : {"location"... part?

Comment: Yes, i wan to keep this structure, Since if i have more than one filters, Sometimes there will be cases like other filters are to be enabled. So match_all wont help i guess.

Comment: are you unable to change the query, simply add/remove filters as needed?

Comment: you can use instead of `term` filter `bool` filter where you can move your `term` filter to either `must`/`must_not`/`should` to get `AND` or `OR` or `NOT` affect

Comment: `GET /Spotafood/Restaurants/_search
    {
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "name": "Al"
        }
    }
    , "filter": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
               {
                   "term": {
                      "locationName": "Salwa Road"
                   }
               },
               {
                   "numeric_range": {
                      "rating": {
                         "from": 1,
                         "to": 5
                      }
                   }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
   } `

Comment: @user1631616 I tried using bool filter .I am using term filter for filtering locations, and i am getting some undesired result(ie, term filter seems not working). Any solution?

Comment: @mconlin i am using java API for elasticsearch . I didnt see an option to remove a filter when not required

Comment: Rewriting Query for each and every combinations of filters is only solution??i think i missed something

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use AndFIlterBuilder and use add() method to create dynamic Queries.

```
public static SearchSourceBuilder search(SearchParams params) {



Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map = params.getParametermapping();

SearchSourceBuilder searchsourcequerybuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();


AndFilterBuilder finalfilter = FilterBuilders.andFilter();
TermsFacetBuilder locationfacet = null;

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
     if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("querystring")) {
    if (entry.getValue().length() == 0) {
        searchSourceBuilder = searchSourceBuilder.query(
            QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()).sort(
                SortBuilders.fieldSort("rating").order(SortOrder.DESC));

    } else {

        searchsourcequerybuilder = searchsourcequerybuilder
            .query(QueryBuilders.fuzzyLikeThisQuery("name")
                .likeText(entry.getValue()));
    }
    }
    if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("locationName")) {
    if (entry.getValue().length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("location Filter is nulll");
        locationfacet = FacetBuilders.termsFacet("locationName")
            .field("locationName").size(20);

    } else {
        locationfacet = FacetBuilders
            .termsFacet("locationName")
            .facetFilter(
                FilterBuilders.termFilter("locationName",
                    entry.getValue()))
                    .field("locationName").size(20);
        finalfilter = finalfilter.add(FilterBuilders.termFilter(
            "locationName", entry.getValue()));
    }
    }
    if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("dinein")) {
    if (entry.getValue().length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Dine in Filter Disabled");
    } else {
        finalfilter = finalfilter.add(FilterBuilders.termFilter(
            "dinein", entry.getValue()));
    }
    }
    if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("rating")) {
    if (entry.getValue().length() == 0) {

        System.out.println("Rating Filter Disabled");
    } else {
        finalfilter = finalfilter.add(FilterBuilders
            .numericRangeFilter("rating")
            .from(entry.getValue()).to("5"));

    }
    }
    if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("barAvailable")) {
    if (entry.getValue().length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("barAvailable Filter Disabled");

    } else {
        finalfilter = finalfilter.add(FilterBuilders.termFilter(
            "barAvailable", entry.getValue()));

    }
    }
}

searchsourcequerybuilder = searchsourcequerybuilder.filter(finalfilter)
    .facet(locationfacet);
System.out.println(searchsourcequerybuilder.toString());
return searchsourcequerybuilder;
}

}
```

Comment: `SearchSourceBuilder` doesn't have a function `filter` in ES 1.1.1. It only lets you add a post filter.